# OpenVPN-AS Apache reverse proxy

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

I have ubuntu server setup with openvpn-access server and apache. I have reverse proxy working for most things I need access to but I cant figure out how to set it up for the connect/admin page of ovpn-as

To access the connect/admin page, the full internal address is:

https://192.168.187.9:943/?src=connect

I would like to be able to access that remotely by going to https://www.domain.com/vpn

Currently I have tried a location directive like:

```
<Location /vpn>
        ProxyPass https://192.168.187.9:943/vpn/?src=connect
        ProxyPassReverse https://192.168.187.9:943/vpn/?src=connect
</Location>
```

But it always results in a 500 internal server error

Whats the correct way to set this up in apache?

EDIT:

In the apache error log I'm seeing this:

```
 [ssl:error] [pid 1991:tid 140374873949952] [remote 192.168.187.9:943] AH01961: SSL Proxy requested for www.domain.com:443 but not enabled [Hint: SSLProxyEngine]
 [proxy:error] [pid 1991:tid 140374873949952] AH00961: HTTPS: failed to enable ssl support for 192.168.187.9:943 (192.168.187.9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, Enable mod_rewrite, proxy & proxy_http modules in Apache for this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/vpn/(.*)$ https://192.168.187.9:943/vpn/$1?src=connect [P,L]
```

Comment: with that I get a 404 error: The requested URL /vpn was not found on this server

Comment: You can try removing the Location tag & putt this rewrite rule inside virtual host section

Comment: I still get the 404. This is in the virtual host that listens on 443 if that makes a difference

Comment: also it seems that navigating to `https://192.168.187.9:943` will also take me to the correct page. so no need for the `?src=connect` maybe that makes things easier?

Comment: Is that 404 page coming from Apache or admin page?.

Comment: Apache. The error is `The requested URL /vpn was not found on this server.`

Comment: What happens, if you access with /vpn/ , add a slash at end

Comment: that gives me a 500 internal server error

Comment: You might need to see the error logs on apache.

Comment: I've attached the error log to the original question. Is this a missing module problem? I can't seem to find the one its mentioning. Besides, other locations work behind SSL...

Comment: Try adding this line above RewriteEngine -> SSLProxyEngine on

Comment: Now Im getting `[proxy:error] (502)Unknown error 502: [client 192.168.187.1:61170] AH01084: pass request body failed to 192.168.187.9:943 (192.168.187.9)`
`[proxy:error] [client 192.168.187.1:61170] AH00898: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server returned by /vpn/`
`[proxy_http:error] [client 192.168.187.1:61170] AH01097: pass request body failed to 192.168.187.9:943 (192.168.187.9) from 192.168.187.1 ()`

Comment: Try the solution from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872482/error-during-ssl-handshake-with-remote-server

Comment: ok so I made the changes in that link, and had to change your line to `RewriteRule ^/vpn/(.*)$ https://192.168.187.9:943/$1?src=connect [P,L]` and now I can see the page! The problem is on that page is a login screen, and when I click the button nothing happens anymore so something about the rewrite broke logging in...the images also appear as broken links....

Answer (score 0):

You are missing this in your VirtualHost:

```
SSLProxyEngine On
```